# Where is page or blog content stored in Shopify and how to efficiently manage template updates?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I'm familiar with platforms like WordPress and other CMSs, where content data is usually stored in a database. However, I've been informed that Shopify handles this differently, possibly using JSON. Can anyone clarify where Shopify stores its page or blog content?

This inquiry is about my friend's website. Their developer mentioned that making changes directly on the live version of the site can be problematic. According to the developer, if they update the template after making content changes, the content will revert to its previous state (content is not hard-coded in to template). As a solution, the developer suggested making changes on a staging site first. However, this approach sometimes requires duplicating efforts, especially when urgent live site edits are necessary.

I'm curious if this is the most efficient way to handle content and template updates in Shopify. Any insights from experienced Shopify users or developers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Content is stored in the merchant's resources. So when they create a blog, and write blog posts, that content is stored at Shopify and rendered as needed from their CDN. Virtually identical to any CMS. You get to decorate that content via templating. Templates are pretty much HTML/CSS so you're in the same domain as 99% of the Internet.

You don't really have much of a question to answer. If you wanted the content of blog posts as JSON, you could ask for the content with API calls. Same as any other system out there.

So if you can drive Wordpress, you can almost certainly figure out Shopify over a cup of coffee, some fiddling, and by accessing the massive amount of documentation for all your questions.

As far as making changes on a live theme go, of course you could do something dumb, and thereby wreck the live experience of a shop. Shopify does a pretty good job trying to save you from being a bonehead, but, it is possible you can make mistakes.